How can I remove the stuck casing for this faucet cartridge?
My new house has a leaky bathtub faucet. The previous owner bought a kit and replaced the shower head and the actual spout of the tub, but then it looks like they ran into the same problem I'm having now, because they left the brand new faucet cartridge (and matching replacement handle) in the box under the sink.
I shut off the water and removed the faucet handle, but the casing over the cartridge will not budge a millimeter. Every video I've watched looks like it should just pop right off and expose the actual faucet cartridge underneath.
Here is a picture:
The part with the blue arrow spins freely, but the part with the red arrow is completely immovable. It doesn't spin at all, and I'm afraid the wall will give way before the faucet if I try to just yank it as hard as I can. (Actually my arm would probably give out first lol.) And anyway, the step-by-step videos I've seen look like I shouldn't need to pull it as hard as I can. There are no other screws holding it in place. How can I remove this piece so I can replace the faucet cartridge?

No yanking, it is screwed in. You might need special tools to remove (unscrew) it

The rounded nose part of the assembly should screw off by turning. The green arrows in the picture below show where there are three sets of flats on opposing sides where a wide smooth jawed tool is meant to be used to turn the part to unthread it.

Picture snipped from the question here.
The original faucet assembly may have come with a custom made stamped flat metal or plastic tool that had a hex shaped hole in it that engaged all six of the flats notches at once.

Thank you!! Is there a specific type of tool I can buy/rent for this purpose, or should I just be using whatever large pliers I can get to kind of fit in those grooves? I'm afraid to damage it by using the wrong tool.

@Lemon I've always used an adjustable wrench, Crescent, with smooth jaws to remove these. Get one that opens up enough for your faucet.

A primitive method if you can not find the special tool.
Use flat rubber strip and put it around. Use players to clamp the rubber to unscrew it.
The rubber provides the protection from scratching, and slip resistance.

Thank you! I was hoping to be able to finish this project (that I thought would be super simple) today, but it doesn't seem like that will be the case. I'll pick up some rubber and try this.

a.k.a. a rubber band. :)
